# OpenGL-ES 2.0 and egl* functions (iOS)

Tags: opengl-es, manual

There're set of definition called "egl" in GLES 1.1: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/

It's the "Native Platform Graphics Interface Layer": 
http://www.khronos.org/opengles/

However, they're not in GLES 2.0: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

So I got some questions:

1. Is this a separated spec from GLES? Or a part of GLES1.1?
2. Where did they gone (in 2.0)? Or still exist (in 2.0)?
3. Where is the manual (guide)?
4. Should I manage eglContext in GLES 2.0 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EGL is a separate spec from OpenGL ES, it can manage contexts for OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 (and algo OpenVG), so it's not really gone.

The latest spec is [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.4.20100721.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think eonil was premature to accept the answer. Unless I am consistently missing things at the "latest spec" Valdenegro provided. For what I find there is that in order to choose the client API for the current context, one must use EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, which is itself supported only in EGL 1.2, which is not on any Android phone I have seen: they are all EGL 1.1.

In EGL 1.0 or 1.1, you can only use the default client version, which is openGL ES.